# number of generators of a quotient group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I am just starting out with abstract algebra and am still getting my head around the first few concepts.

We have been asked to find out how many elements of the Z mod 6 quotient group are generators.

Does this mean that I look for the least amount of elements required to generate the Z mod 6 group?

or all of them.

I am not sure this is right but from my understanding the Z mod 6 group contains 6 equivalence classes with the [0] equivalence class being the identity.

If I took [1] I think its inverse would be [5] as that would give me back [0].

So would the generators be {[1],[2],[3]}?

As the inverses would give me [5] and [4] and the inverse of [3] would give me the identity?

Any clarification would be much appreciated, I think my confusion comes from not quite yet fully grasping the concepts.

Also if I am looking for ALL the genrators would {[3],[4],[5]} also work?

Comment: $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ has $\phi(6)=2$ generators. The result is (see the duplicate):" An integer $k\in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ iff $\gcd(n,k)=1$. For $n=6$ we can only take $k=1,5$.

Comment: You seem a little confused about what a generator of a group is. Have a careful look at the definitions. You are being asked "for how many $x \in \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is it the case that $x$ generates $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$?". You should not be thinking about whether multiple elements at once generate the whole group, because that's not what's being asked. For example, $[1]$ *does* generate $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, but $[3]$ *doesn't*. Can you see why?

Comment: By the way you are *not* looking for the least amount of elements required to generate $\mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$; that least amount is $1$. Instead, you are looking for *how many* generators $\mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$ has, i.e. how many single elements $\mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$ has, each of which on its own generates the whole group.